# error C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string (__thiscall ClassName::* )(std::string)' to 'std::string (__cdecl *)(std::string)

Tags: visual-c++, boost, event-handling, c++-cli, function-pointers

I'm making a unmanaged application to handle an event fired in c# here.
FYI:: I want to handle a custom event when my Name property in C# class is changed.
I have gone through the following links:

[Explanation about passing pointer to member function as parameter](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C++-ptmf4.pdf)

[Something similar to my problem.But couldn't understand the solution](http://www.questionhub.com/StackOverflow/1540859)

Now,
In NativeApp.cpp,*I have a member function which is passed as a function pointer as parameter in a method present in the c++/CLI wrapper*

```
//NativeApp.cpp
std::string Class1::FunctionToBePointed(std::string msg)
{
   return msg;
}

void Class1::NativeMethod()
{
UnmanagedWrapperClass* unmanagedWrapperClass=new UnmanagedWrapperClass();
unmanagedWrapperClass->WrapperMethod(&Class1::FunctionToBePointed,"Hello")
}
```

In Wrapper.h,

```
//Wrapper.h
class __declspec(dllexport) UnmanagedWrapperClass
{
 boost::signals2::signal<void(std::string)>signalEvent;
 void WrapperMethod(std::string (*GetCallBack)(std::string),std::string value);

}
```

When I call the WrapperMethod from NativeApp.cpp,

1. I subscribe my EventHandlerWrapper to a c# event
2. connect the function pointer to my boost signal signalEvent.
3. Set the Name property of the CSharp Class

   When the Name Property is set, c# event is fired, EventHandlerWrapper method in Wrapper.cpp is executed.Looks like this::

   void  EventHandlerWrapper(string value)

   ```
   {

   if(signalEvent.connected())
   ```

   {
   signalEvent(value);
   }

For some reasons I can't make my FunctionToBePointed(std::string) method as a non-member function.

P.S:: All ears for any other design approach.

Comment: @megabyte1024,While I am building my NativeApp.cpp, I am getting the above mentioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your real use-case can you simply make FunctionToBePointed a **static method**?

```
static std::string Class1::FunctionToBePointed(std::string msg)
{
   return msg;
}
```

If yes your code should work.

The reason is that **instance methods** are implicitly called with an **hidden *this* pointer**, this is the ***thiscall* calling convention**, whereas **static methods** simply use the ***cdecl* convention** because they don't work on any instance.

**EDIT:**

A sample with **Boost::bind**:

The MyClass C# class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate{};

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The C++/CLI wrapper:

Wrapper.h:

```
class WrapperPrivateStuff;

class __declspec(dllexport) UnmanagedWrapperClass
{
    private: WrapperPrivateStuff* _private;
    public: void changeIt(std::string newName);
    public: void WrapperMethod(boost::function<std::string(std::string)> GetCallBack);
    public: UnmanagedWrapperClass();
};
```

Wrapper.cpp:

```
#using "MyClass.dll"

#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include "Wrapper.h"

#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <msclr\event.h>

class WrapperPrivateStuff
{
    public: boost::signals2::signal<void(std::string)>signalEvent;
    public: msclr::auto_gcroot<MyClass^> a;
    public: void EventHandlerWrapper(System::Object^, System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventArgs^ args)
    {
        this->signalEvent(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(a->Name));
    }
    public: WrapperPrivateStuff()
    {
        a = gcnew MyClass();
        a->PropertyChanged += MAKE_DELEGATE(System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventHandler, EventHandlerWrapper);
    }

    BEGIN_DELEGATE_MAP(WrapperPrivateStuff)
        EVENT_DELEGATE_ENTRY(EventHandlerWrapper, System::Object^, System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventArgs^)
    END_DELEGATE_MAP()
};

void UnmanagedWrapperClass::changeIt(std::string newName)
{
    this->_private->a->Name = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(newName);
}

UnmanagedWrapperClass::UnmanagedWrapperClass()
{
    this->_private = new WrapperPrivateStuff();
}

void UnmanagedWrapperClass::WrapperMethod(boost::function<std::string(std::string)> GetCallBack)
{
    _private->signalEvent.connect(GetCallBack);
}
```

And the native application, test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include "Wrapper.h"

class Class1
{
    private: std::string name;

    public: Class1(std::string name)
        : name(name)
    {
    }

    public: std::string FunctionToBePointed(std::string msg)
    {
        std::cout << "Hey it's " << name << "! Got: " << msg << std::endl;
        return msg;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    UnmanagedWrapperClass wrapper;
    Class1 class1("Ed");

    wrapper.WrapperMethod(boost::bind(&Class1::FunctionToBePointed, &class1, _1));
    wrapper.changeIt("azerty"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
>test.exe
Hey it's Ed! Got: azerty
```

I have a more generic solution but it is really ugly. :(

Let me know if this fix your issue...

Comment: @Pragmateek...for some reasons, I can't make it static. I am familiar with this answer and syntax Sir.If u can provide me any other workaround, that would be more than helpful.

Comment: So I fear you can't because AFAIK pointers to functions don't carry any instance information. You'll either have to **pass the object to work on as an additional parameter** or use a **wrapper** like **std::function/boost::function** with **binding**.